# A member array contains instances of a class. Can't decide where to put a method which modifies a variable of this class

Tags: c++, data-structures

There is a two dimensional array of `Block`s in the class `Map`. I need a method to change the variable `value` in the class `Block`.

```
class Block
{
    Block(BlockValue blockValue = BLANK);

    //first solution
    void Block::setValue(BlockValue blockValue, Map &map);

    void setImage(BlockValue blockValue, int n = 0);

    //the value to be changed
    BlockValue value;

    static std::vector< std::vector<sf::Image> > images;

    ...
};

 class Map
 {
     std::vector< std::vector<Block> > blocks;

     //second solution
     void setBlockValue(BlockValue blockValue, int i, int j);

     ...
 };
```

I can think of two solutions:

1. I create a `Block::setValue(BlockValue blockValue, Map &map)` in the class `Block` and call it from the `Map` in the following way:

   `blocks[i][j].setValue(blockValue, this);`
2. I create a `setBlockValue(BlockValue blockValue, int i, int j)` method int the class `Map`. The problem with this solution is that I can't use my constructor for `Block`:

   `Block::Block(BlockValue blockValue) { setValue(blockValue); }`

Which solution would you recommend?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that it is important that the method have access to the array of `Block`s. That's why I included the `Map &map` in the parameter list of the first method. I apologize for this terrible mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, from a clarity point of view, I'd combine both. e.g.

```
class Block
{
  public:
    // setter to set the block value
    void setValue(BlockValue blockValue);

  private:
    //the value to be changed
    BlockValue value;
};
```

and in `Map` have a method to set the `BlockValue` for a specific location

```
class Map
{
  public
    void setBlockValue(BlockValue blockValue, int i, int j)
    {
      blocks[i][j].setValue(blockValue); // call the specific setter
    }

  private:
    std::vector< std::vector<Block> > blocks;
};
```

Comment: Your solution seems appropriate, only the Block::setValue(BlockValue blockValue) method doesn't have acces to the array of Blocks. Sorry but I haven't told you about this in the original post. I have already edited it.

Comment: You are introducing a circular dependency this way - why not simply pass the `blocks` array to the specific block in the `setValue` call?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the number of lines of code and also improve efficiency with:

```
class Map
 {
     std::vector< std::vector<Block> > blocks;
     ...

     Block& block(int i, int j) {
         return blocks[i*num_cols + j];
     }
 };
```

Returning a reference will allow the caller to use assignment

```
mymap.block(i, j) = ...;
```

and will save you from having to provide separate calls for reading and writing.

Comment: Your code is very interesting but I can't use it. The original post didn't cover my problem fully, I have already edited it. I am sorry for this mistake. I would be happy to use the modified version of your code if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think first solution more flexible.
If Block will past it self to map, your can do what you want on pre insert to map, or on post insert moments.